# ожидает b а получаем строку. Ошибка при вызове hmac.new(): TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
BTC_api_key = "TP6XBFJ0-N51EGL1N-HHX1XI3X-8QZPZEN9-W1MJ7ESO"
BTC_api_secret = "44d2c58b41077ef0f0bb52e52374294bc36682d221d2a5ce6fc6c18f4afd19b6"
nonce = 1
dater = ()

H = hmac.new(BTC_api_secret, digestmod=hashlib.sha512)
sign = H.hexdigest()
headers = {
    "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Key":BTC_api_key,
    "Sign":sign,
    "method":"getInfo",
    "nonce": nonce
}
H.update(dater)
```

И ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File 
"C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\ \test2.py", line 16, in 
<module> H = hmac.new(BTC_api_secret, digestmod=hashlib.sha512) File 
"C:\Users\владимир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32‌​\lib\hmac.py", 
line 144, in new return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod) File 
"C:\Users\владимир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32‌​\lib\hmac.py", 
line 42, in init raise TypeError("key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 
%r" % type(key).__name__) TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but 
got 'str'
```

Используется Python 3.5

Comment: Нужно приводить полный стек с ошибкой, по нему понятно в какой функции возникла проблема, а так, скорее всего проблема в `hmac.new`

Comment: gil9red Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\ \test2.py", line 16, in <module>
    H = hmac.new(BTC_api_secret, digestmod=hashlib.sha512)
  File "C:\Users\владимир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\hmac.py", line 144, in new
    return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod)
  File "C:\Users\владимир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\hmac.py", line 42, in __init__
    raise TypeError("key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got %r" % type(key).__name__)
TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str'

Comment: В следующий раз в вопрос добавляйте, а так по трассе проблема и в правда была в `hmac.new`

Comment: gil9red ясно, а какая проблема то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяйте в коде на:

H = hmac.new(BTC_api_secret.encode(), digestmod='sha512').hexdigest()

Answer (score 4):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/hmac.html):

> ```
> mac.new(key, msg=None, digestmod=None)
> ```
>
> Parameter key can be a bytes or bytearray object.
> Parameter msg can be of any type supported by hashlib.

Поэтому, поменяйте в коде на:

```
H = hmac.new(BTC_api_secret.encode(), digestmod=hashlib.sha512)
```

Comment: gil9red да, я так пробовал следующая ошибка: Traceback (самый последний вызов последнего): Файл "C: \ Users \ владимир \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python35-32 \ мои уроки \ test2.py", строка 23, в < модуль> H.update (датировщик) Файл "C: \ Users \ владимир \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python35-32 \ Lib \ hmac.py", строка 93, в обновление self.inner.update (МСГ) TypeError : объект поддержки буфера API требуется

Comment: @владимиржалеев, какой-то странный стек трейс ) Фигня у вас в `H.update(dater)`, `dater` это кортеж (tuple), а в `update` нужно байтовый массив помещать, ну например: `dater = b'hexhex'`

Comment: gil9red примерно так? hmac.new(
    key = b'TP6XBFJ0-N51EGL1N-HHX1XI3X-8QZPZEN9-W1MJ7ESO',
    msg = open ('key.txt,', 'rb').read(),
    digestmod = hashlib.sha512,
).hexdigest()

Comment: @владимиржалеев, похоже да, но и в dater нужно другое значение, иначе будет та ошибка -- требуется объект с поддержкой API буфера

Comment: gil9red спасибо буду мучать его дальше, да и какой на примере объект?

Comment: @владимиржалеев, писал же -- байтовый массив, например объект типа bytes или bytearray, bytes это -- b"dfsdfsdfsdf", или "dfsdfsdfsdf".encode()

Comment: gil9red понял,значит план можно так реализовать; все ключи и переменные записать в файл / прочесть из файла и преобразовать во что-либо другое,да?

Comment: gil9red сделал так H.update(b'headers') и ошибок нету

Comment: @владимиржалеев, мне любопытно, а чем мой ответ вас не устроил? :) Ведь тот повторяет мое решение и в контексте вашего кода ломает его (из-за вызова hexdigest, который вы делаете для sign)